# Azure Bastion - Troubleshooting Connection Issues

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-bastion

> The target machine is either currently unreachable or username/password is not correct. Please re-verify your credentials. If the problem persists please contact support.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: This is not a programming question, so you're in the wrong place. And if it persists, they are asking you to contact support...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cloud service connection issue

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the correct credentials to connect to the vm and also try to reset the password from the azure portal and try connecting.

if the problem persists please submit a support ticket from azure portal>>help+support section.